# Recycler view adding item at position creating empty views and not updating data on added position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

adding a item dynamically which is not giving me desired output, with static data its working fine but not with dynamic data. view are repeating sometimes and some times its creating empty views.

Fragment service call:

```
public void getDataFromServer() {
        try {
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            String url = ApplicationConstants.GET_ITEMS;

            if (networkClient!= null)
                networkClient.getData(url, params, new ItemsDataListener());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ItemsDataListener extends ResponseHandler{

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] byteResponse) {
            try {
                String response = new String(byteResponse);
                if (response != null && !response.isEmpty()) {                   
                    Model model=new Gson().fromJson(response,Model.class);
                    mAdapter.addItem(model, 2);

                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, byte[] byteResponse) {

        }
    }
```

this is the method in my adapter:

```
public class ItemCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context = null;
    private ArrayList<Model> itemList;


    public ItemCardAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        itemList= new ArrayList<>();

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, final int viewType) {

            View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.single_item_view, viewGroup, false);
            ItemCardHolder itemCardHolder = new ItemCardHolder(v);

            return itemCardHolder ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int i) {

         (holder instanceof ItemCardHolder) {
            Model model=itemList.get(i)
            ((ItemCardHolder) holder).populateData(model);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

            return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder);
            ((ItemCardHolder) holder).cardview.clearAnimation();
    }



     public void addItem(Model newItem, int position) {
            itemlist.add(position, newItem);
            this.notifyItemInserted(position);
            this.notifyItemChanged(position);

        }

    public void clearData() {
        itemList.clear();
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: put all your code here please

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here

```
mAdapter.addItem(model, 2);
```

It will try to add item at 2 position always even if no data. try to get item count from adapter and then try to add item.